# how to parse and reduce multiple if condition to one line in text file?

Tags: python, file, text, io

I try to analyze old PL/1 source files after normalization it with Python to make it more efficient. There are too many if conditions, but I can't find a way to reduce this effectively. like this:

```
if cond == 'A' 
 | cond == 'B'
 | cond == 'C'
 | cond_ex == 'A_EX'
 | cond == 'D'
 | cond_ex == 'B_EX'
 then;
```

I want to change and reduce code like this:

```
if cond in ('A','B','C','D') | cond_ex in ('A_EX','B_EX') then;
```

Can you tell me solution to parse those code using python regex or text replace?

Comment: To do this properly you are going to have to write a full PL/I parser. That is *a very tall order*.

Comment: `re.match('^[ABCD]$', cond)`

Comment: Since you single letter are in sequence you could take advantage of the collating sequence with `if cond > ord("A")-1 and cond < ord("D")+1`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse data as following and make an if statement according to your need.

```
>>> a = """if cond == 'A' 
...  | cond == 'B'
...  | cond == 'C'
...  | cond_ex == 'A_EX'
...  | cond == 'D'
...  | cond_ex == 'B_EX'
...  then;"""
>>> b = a.replace("if", "").replace("then","").replace(";","").replace("|","").replace(" ","")
>>> c = b.split()
>>> print c
["cond=='A'", "cond=='B'", "cond=='C'", "cond_ex=='A_EX'", "cond=='D'", "cond_ex=='B_EX'"]
```